# Hide HERE Map API Key to use with document object

Tags: javascript, node.js, here-api, api-key

I'm making an express application that requires a map. I'm using the HERE Maps API for javascript boilerplate to render the map. https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js

I am already using the *dotenv* package for environment variables (port, host) in my application. But I don't know how to hide the map API key in the backend when I need to use the `document` object to render the map. Currently, I'm using a separate file *config.js* to store the variable but the key is still visible in the frontend.

In conclusion, I can hide the API key in the backend but I can't render the map in the backend and I can render the map in the frontend but I can't hide the API key in the frontend. **How can I both hide the API key and render the map?**

**Minimum, reproducible, example:-**

*Structure of root directory*

```
| public
    | config.js
    | map.js
| views
    | index.pug
| .env
| index.js
| package.json
```

*index.pug*

```
doctype html
html
    head
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css")
        script(src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js")
        script(src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js")
        script(src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js")
        script(src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js")
        script(src="config.js" defer)
        script(src="map.js" defer)
    body
        #map(data-lat=lat data-lng=lng)
```

*config.js*

```
const config = {
    MAP_API_KEY: `${API_KEY}`
}
```

*map.js*

```
const mapEl = document.getElementById('map')
const platform = new H.service.Platform({
    apikey: config.MAP_API_KEY
})
const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers()
const map = new H.Map(mapEl, defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
    center: {
        lat: parseFloat(mapEl.dataset.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(mapEl.dataset.lng)
    },
    zoom: 5,
    pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
})
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize())
const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map))
const ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use headless chrome (puppeteer maybe) which loads only the map, then get a screenshot of it and use the screenshot on your frontend.

You cannot render a map on frontend without an api key. Maybe you should consider restrict api access to specific domain(s)/ip(s) instead.

Comment: Using a screenshot disables the ui functionality of the map. How do we preserve it?

Comment: you can’t do that without an api key.